# Method to track price drops for a product on a user's wishlist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, notifications, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have these tables/models:

```
Product
- id
- last_updated_date
- name
- price

User
- id
- name

WishlistItem
- id
- user_id
- product_id
```

The Product table has a few million records and is being updated automatically each night via a data import (inserting into a new table, dropping the old one). I basically have read-only access to that table/model.

If a product is on a user's wishlist and the price drops, I'd like to be able to notify that user. What methods can be used to do this?

I have a couple of ideas:

1. Keep track of the Product.last_updated_date in the wishlist model and periodically poll the product table to see if it has been updated. This sounds like a horrible/non-scaleable solution.
2. Some sort of Postgres View or Function that triggers when the Product table is updated? I'm new to postgres so I'm not yet sure if this is even possible.
3. Something amazing that you will suggest that I haven't thought of :)

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

---

UPDATE:
One idea that came up was caching the current price inside the wishlist entry itself, ie:

```
WishlistItem
- id
- user_id
- product_id
- price
```

... then, after the import, I could compare WishlistItem.price with Product.price and notify accordingly. Although it would work, this approach seems a bit wasteful since every WishlistItem for every user will essentially have the same cached copy of the price data and I'll have to update every list with the new price if there's an update. I'm not sure there's a way around it though.

---

UPDATE:
In the end I decided I should probably just be tracking all versions of the data so that I can use standard on update triggers. This also allows me to have a record of all price changes so I can track pricing trends, etc.

Comment: Your update is in line of my suggestion below, denormalized price. Since you replace your product-table you need to log your orginial prices in some other table. Notifications need to be marked, either as you say, by updating the wishlist-table, there are other solutions as, having a notification-table and only allow one notification per user/product (simply by adding id of wishlist and making it unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an update trigger on `Product` but it sounds like the `Product` table is not actually being updated, it is being replaced; if this is the case then there is no update to trigger the trigger so you'll have to do it the hard way by caching the price in `Wishlist` (as user247245 notes) and scanning `Product` for price changes.

If `Products` is being updated rather than replaced wholesale, then an update trigger could be used to note when a price changes and arrange to have the interested parties notified. The trigger would probably queue up the notifications by inserting them into a separate table (to avoid locking up the `Products` update) called, say `Product_price_changes`; then, when the `Products` update is done, a separate task can compare `Product_price_changes` to `Wishlist`, notify the interested users, and finish off by deleting everything in `Product_price_changes`.

Note that recent versions of PostgreSQL you can restrict an update trigger to only fire when a column changes rather than firing on every row change.

Comment: It seems like an update trigger would be the right way to go if the table wasn't being replaced wholesale, but it is. Unfortunately the `Products` table is huge and importing the data takes a really long time. Replacing the table (rather than UPSERT-ing rows) speeds it up significantly but I lose the ability to use an update trigger. I guess I'll  have to evaluate which is more important: total import speed or the ability to have an update trigger. I might be able to mimic the same functionality with a ruby observer that creates `product_price_changes` after the import is finished I suppose.

Comment: How often do the values in `Product` really change? If the daily product data dump comes from an outside source you might be able to work out a diff/patch deal (which might even be a simple diff(1) on text files) system to trim it down to a small set of changes, then apply just those changes to the `Product` table. The trick is to trim down the work load or spread it out into small chunks to avoid locking up `Product` and getting in the online system's way. Hopefully the "big database" crew will show up tomorrow with some fresh ideas.

Comment: Well, they might not change that often, but the problem is the sheer volume of records and data I'm working with... it's several million records total, so if even a smallish percentage of them are updated, it's still quite a lot of data. (I'm importing other tables as well, this is just one piece in a somewhat large data set.) You're right though, I may need to rethink replacing the tables entirely on import...

Comment: Right, doesn't matter how many needles you have if your haystack is the size of a city. Rethinking the "replace the tables rather than update them "strategy might be the way to go; replacing that would also make it easy to add foreign keys to ensure referential integrity: broken code can be fixed, broken data may be irreparable.

Comment: In the end, it seems like the right answer would be to track the different versions of the data after each import. This would also help in being able to see pricing trends over time. You're right, broken code can be fixed, but broken data is a different issue altogether. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a field "price" to the wishlist table. After update of product-table query for lower prices and generate a notification table as a result

regards,
/t